# Proving condition for spanning vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have highlighted the bit I don't understand, what does it mean by in the linear form? And didn't the proof already state that 4 lines above?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *linear form* is as outlined in the last sentence of the first paragraph, namely the linear function of the entries of **b**: $l$(**b**)$ = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i b_i$ corresponding to a zero row.

The statement which is four lines above what you highlighted states that the coefficient of $b_i$ is $1$ *at the start* i.e., before we start the Gaussian elimination process (by switching rows, multiplying rows by scalars etc). The highlighted statement is saying that if the original $i$-th row (after at least one step in the Gaussian elimination process) is a zero row, it must have become a zero row by addition/s of multiples of one or more above rows. So the linear form on the right of the vertical line will be ($b_i$ + linear combination of the $b_j's$), where $j \neq i$. That is, $b_i$ plus a linear combination of the other entries of **b**. In this expression, the coefficient of $b_i$ is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: No problem at all.